# How to return simple type from async method on a rust async_trait?

Tags: rust, async-await

Example implementation

```rust
#[async_trait]
trait ExampleTrait {
    async fn example_method(&self) -> bool;
}

pub struct ExampleStruct {}

#[async_trait]
impl ExampleTrait for ExampleStruct {
    async fn example_method(&self) -> bool {
        true
    }    
}
```

Trying to compile this implementation I have the error:

```
async fn example_method(&self) -> bool;
                                  ---- type in trait
...
async fn example_method(&self) -> bool {
    |                             ^^^^ expected `bool`, found opaque type
    |
    = note: expected fn pointer `fn(&ExampleStruct) -> bool`
               found fn pointer `fn(&ExampleStruct) -> impl Future`
```

I know the signature in `example_method` is expanded to return a Future implementation, thus the last message `note...`
async_trait documentation doesn't explain how to get arount this case which should straightforward imo... Anybody knows how to solve this?

Comment: Your example works on the playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2e9626f1e66832cab78ab3c486628280 Are you sure it's the same code you posted here?

Comment: Yes (the code is the same), but I've seem my mistake, it is not in the snippet, but I was bringing the crate into my `[dev-dependencies]` instead of `[dependencies]`, so when checking or building the crate wouldn't be brought into scope.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have not brought the macro in scope, so the transformation is not performed, resulting in the error. If you bring `async_trait` into scope, the code compiles:

```rust
use async_trait::async_trait;

#[async_trait]
trait ExampleTrait {
    async fn example_method(&self) -> bool;
}

pub struct ExampleStruct {}

#[async_trait]
impl ExampleTrait for ExampleStruct {
    async fn example_method(&self) -> bool {
        true
    }    
}
```

Comment: Although I didn't put it in the snippet, I'm bringing it into scope with the `use` statement as in your example.

Comment: but your answer made me check how I'm bringing the crate into scope and into my project, and noticed I placed it into `[dev-dependencies]` (my bad here). So the problem was all on my side. Thank you